# What should I do if one of the process in pool.map function crashes?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool, try-except

I am using `map` function from python multiprocessing Pool to create an array for some iterations:

```
n=number_processes
for _ in range(100):
    ...
    PARAMS=[scipy.stats.norm.rvs(loc=mean,scale=sigma) for _ in range(n)]
    with Pool(n) as pool:
        p=numpy.array(list(pool.map(calculate_model,PARAMS)))
    ...
    ...
```

where the function `caluclate_model` evaluates the return value using a C++ library. The iterable `PARAMS` is a list of different values randomly selected(under certain bounds) at each iteration.

The problem is that for some value in `PARAMS`, the function `calculate_model` crashes giving an error:

```
*** Error in `python3': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000004d36d40 ***
```

Since this is a bug in the C++ library due to memory allocation, I cannot catch it in python. At this point, the process on which the calculations were running stops, spawns a new process and goes to sleep immediately while the other processes are still running. When the other processes are finished, all the processes then go to sleep including the newly spawned one which never started evaluating.

My questions regarding this issue are:

1. When the process crashes, why does it spawn a new process and goes to sleep?
2. Is there a way to handle this without debugging the C++ library?

Comment: I am not sure why all process are going to sleep, but you can use `try/except` to catch the error in the worker. That should at least let you handle it.

Comment: I cannot use try/except as the error comes from C++ library, not in my python code. Honestly, I am not even sure how to go about fixing the bug in C++, which is why I wanted to understand why processes are going to sleep and hoping to work around it in python itself.